# Java Simple Binary Tree check equals

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, equals

I can't figure out why this `equals` function is not working:

```
class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

    TreeNode(int x) {
        val = x;
    }
    
    public boolean equals(TreeNode other) {
        if (this == null && other == null) {
            return true;
        } else if (this == null || other == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return this.val == other.val
                    && this.left.equals(other.left)
                    && this.right.equals(other.right);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the main issue is I can't compare a null TreeNode, but in the setup I have pointed out already how to handle the null?

```
TreeNode a = new TreeNode(5);
TreeNode b = new TreeNode(5);
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // >>> NullPointerException
```

Comparison above started with non-null, but eventually it will hit null when branching to a null left or null right. One way to work is to extract the same method above, into a static method:

```
public static boolean isEqual(TreeNode self, TreeNode other) {
    if (self == null && other == null) {
        return true;
    } else if (self == null || other == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return self.val == other.val
                && isEqual(self.left, other.left)
                && isEqual(self.right, other.right);
    }
}
```

This will work fine:

```
TreeNode a = new TreeNode(5);
TreeNode b = new TreeNode(5);
System.out.println(TreeNode.isEqual(a, b)); // >>> true
```

Below will also work, to avoid `this.left/right` to be `null`, looks stupid, but it is java

```
public boolean equals(TreeNode other) {

    if (this.left == null && other.left == null && this.right == null && other.right == null) {
        return this.val == other.val;
    } else if (this.left != null && other.left != null && this.right != null && other.right != null) {
        return this.val == other.val && this.left.equals(other.left) && this.right.equals(other.right);
    } else if (this.left != null && other.left != null && this.right == null && other.right == null) {
        return this.val == other.val && this.left.equals(other.left);
    } else if (this.left == null && other.left == null && this.right != null && other.right != null) {
        return this.val == other.val && this.right.equals(other.right);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `a.equals(....)`, what is exactly `a` when you invoke this? hint: it is not something that is not null.

Comment: `a` is a `TreeNode` that is `null`?

Comment: right, and calling a method on a `null` will result in?

Comment: In python, the exact code will run just fine. Can you suggest how should I avoid this situation?

Comment: I am not comparing, I am just stating the fact.

Comment: it didn't help.

Comment: can you detail why then?

Comment: still getting `NullPointerException`. Can you please write out how to use `java.util.Objects.equals` in the function?

Comment: see my updates, you are not being very helpful just showing me `java.util.Objects.equals(a, b)`. You need to handle when one is null and the other is not!

Comment: `this == null` cannot be, and please add `@Override` before equals.

Comment: @JoopEggen I tried to add @Override, and it was not allowed? It says `Method does not override method from its superclass`

Comment: Yes, because it is `equals(Object)`. _That_ equals method is the one used in Set and other container classes. Hence the code is a bit misleading/confusing. That is all I wanted to express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a is null. Therefore, the invocation of "equals" will raise an immediate NullPointerException without the equals method will be called.

Two issues that may confuse you:

1. In the first implementation, checking "this==null" is redundant (this can't be null in this context).
2. the "this.left" and "this.right" null checks are also redundant, because they are primitives, and can never be null.

By my opinion, it should be something like:

```
public boolean equals(TreeNode other) {
    if (other == null) {
        return false;
    }

    // Different Values
    if (this.val != other.val) {
        return false;
    }

    if (this.left == null && other.left != null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.left != null && !this.left.equals(other.left)) {
        return false;
    }
    
    if (this.right == null && other.right != null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.right != null && !this.right.equals(other.right)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: @jxie0755 Why should they write code? In java, no non-static method will work if the object is null. So why check if ``this == null``?

Comment: Added it in the above answer.

Comment: Thank you, I think your codes looks much better, and I learned that `this` can never be `null`. This problem only goes with `.equals` due to the inheritance. If I created a static method, this code will work just fine.